# How to create a PDA and enable data storage?

Tags: spl-token, transfer, spl-token-program, authority

I'm using PDA to hold the funds and the smart contract will sign it to transfer funds from the PDA to anyone.

What's the best way to create a PDA to store multiple NFTs/tokens and also custom data into it?

Here's a simple function which I wrote to withdraw SOL from PDA. But need to enable data storage with manipulating data.

```
pub fn withdraw_funds(
    ctx: Context<WithdrawFunds>,
    receiver: Pubkey,
    lamports: u64,
) -> ProgramResult {
    if ctx.accounts.destination.to_account_info().is_writable {
        let (pda, bump_seed) = Pubkey::find_program_address(&[VAULT_PDA_SEED], ctx.program_id);
        let invoke = invoke_signed(
            &system_instruction::transfer(&pda, &receiver, lamports),
            &[
                ctx.accounts.vault.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.destination.to_account_info(),
                ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
            ],
            &[&[VAULT_PDA_SEED.as_ref(), &[bump_seed]]],
        );
        if invoke.is_ok() {}
        
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

How to modify the data in PDA?

Comment: I've retracted my close vote, and now suggest you remove the second question.  Check out this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68997169/solana-anchor-rust-how-to-convert-a-public-key-into-an-accountinfo-type) before you ask the second question in it's own post.

Comment: Would you mind wrap your code properly in a code-block, otherwise it's very difficult to read.

Answer (score 8):

Coin flip would be really difficult to implement as a smart contract because it traditionally requires a source of [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) in order to create a random(-ish) result. The problem is that introducing randomness means the program will no longer be deterministic and that makes it *impossible* for validators to replicate the results of the program and agree about the outcome. This is why the `rand` crate is [not available](https://docs.solana.com/developing/on-chain-programs/developing-rust#restrictions) to on-chain programs.

Alternatively, you could take a non-traditional approach and implement a deterministic variant of coin-flip. However, since this result is calculable in a predictable manner it becomes very easy to cheat! Anyone can run the code themselves and only submit a coin to play when they *know* what the next result will be.

Another option would be to use an [oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockchain_oracle) or an off-chain resource that interacts with the on-chain contract *after* coins have been submitted.

Once you determine how to implement the actual "flip" mechanism, Paul wrote [a very nice tutorial](https://paulx.dev/blog/2021/01/14/programming-on-solana-an-introduction/#instruction-rs-part-1-general-code-structure-and-the-beginning-of-the-escrow-program-flow) that illustrates how a smart contract might hold and later distribute tokens to a user.

Comment: “Verified Randomness Function”
https://github.com/orao-network/solana-vrf

Comment: That's interesting @MmmHmm. Wonder what is meant by "[an unbiased _randomness service_ whose result can be verified](https://orao.medium.com/orao-vrf-at-solana-hacker-house-austin-tx-876767000a4b)". _Sounds like_ off-chain randomness thats published as some auditable seed data to solana. If so, once it's on-chain, contracts can derive predictable outcomes from it. I can't seem to find an explanation of the on-chain solution anywhere though. You?

Comment: This answer applied to the question as it was originally phrased. Since several people found this answer helpful, I've [reposted the original question](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/1218/how-to-setup-a-simple-coin-flip-smart-contract) roughly paraphrased for reference.

Answer (score 0):

@Nate is correct that there is no trivial source of randomness for your smart contract. This may be surprising as it is somewhat unique to Solana.

> Can someone please help me understanding this scenario on how to implement transfer funds from contract to user.

This part of the question can still be answered. I would use
[anchor-spl-token](https://crates.io/crates/anchor-spl-token) to make a transfer CPI to transfer user funds to a PDA account, and then once the result of the game is determined (possibly in a subsequent instruction), transfer funds from the PDA account to a user.