# Is randomness achievable on-chain?

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, random, program-designs

How, for example, might you implement a simple "coin-flip" game as an on-chain Solana program?

The concept is that a player deposits a coin or token, and the onchain program generates a "win" or a "lose" with a 50/50 chance.

Comment: the coin flip example doesn't particularly elaborate the question.  it would be better to discuss the properties of "randomness" that you desire

Answer (score 3):

Coin flip would be really difficult to implement as a smart contract because it traditionally requires a source of [entropy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)) in order to create a random(-ish) result. The problem is that introducing randomness means the program will no longer be deterministic and that makes it *impossible* for validators to replicate the results of the program and agree about the outcome. This is why the `rand` crate is [not available](https://docs.solana.com/developing/on-chain-programs/developing-rust#restrictions) to on-chain programs.

Alternatively, you could take a non-traditional approach and implement a deterministic variant of coin-flip. However, since this result is calculable in a predictable manner it becomes very easy to cheat! Anyone can run the code themselves and only submit a coin to play when they *know* what the next result will be.

Another option would be to use an [oracle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blockchain_oracle) or an off-chain resource that interacts with the on-chain contract *after* coins have been submitted.

Once you determine how to implement the actual "flip" mechanism, Paul wrote [a very nice tutorial](https://paulx.dev/blog/2021/01/14/programming-on-solana-an-introduction/#instruction-rs-part-1-general-code-structure-and-the-beginning-of-the-escrow-program-flow) that illustrates how a smart contract might hold and later distribute tokens to a user.

Answer (score 2):

Switchboard just recently carried out a Verifiable Random Function (VRF) workshop in their Discord, here are some links to help you.

[Video](https://youtu.be/OJtGFexVFII)

[Implementation Walkthrough](https://github.com/switchboard-xyz/vrf-demo-walkthrough)

[vrf-flip game](https://vrf-demo.switchboard.xyz/)

[vrf-flip open source repo](https://github.com/switchboard-xyz/vrf-flip)

Answer (score 1):

Switchboard has an oracle that you can use to achieve randomness

`https://docs.switchboard.xyz/randomness`

They have an example using anchor

`https://github.com/switchboard-xyz/vrf-cpi-example`

Comment: Thanks @vicyyn. https://docs.switchboard.xyz/randomness explains that Switchboard's solution is *pseudorandom* (deterministic, not truly random). Since producing the next pseudorandom result requires access to a private key, it _needs_ to be done off chain and then published to an account so it can be verified & used. It looks like [reading a value](https://github.com/switchboard-xyz/switchboard-v2/blob/main/libraries/rs/src/vrf.rs#L448) just checks the latest data from the on-chain account where it was already published. I don't think this is _generated_ on-chain.

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out yourself, the answer is "No, you cannot achieve randomness on-chain with Solana".

All validators need to get to the same new state after each transaction, so Solana is functioning in a deterministic manner.

Oracles are a possibility, but then you have to trust some off-chain generator to be truly random.

Comment: Yeah thanks for chiming in @AllBlooming. I posted this because the [original time this was asked](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/974/how-to-create-a-pda-and-enable-data-storage/981#981) got changed into something completely different after others found the answer helpful. There used to be a note on this Q to that effect but it was suggested to remove it for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the `coin-flip` games you see use some form of `off-chain` `random` source (`Oracle` is just someone pushing into the chain something generated outside).

There are ways to generate pseudo random numbers purely in `solana`.

But the main issue is that you don't know their distribution and if you want to base a game on them, it can greatly affect it.