# Cost of logging vs storing data in Solana programs?

Tags: solana-program, rent, logs

The Way Ethereum stores data through Events I want to do the same on Solana but not sure
How do the compare the cost of storing it in logs or in Solana programs?
Are there any other cheaper ways to store data directly on the Solana blockchain?

Answer (score 2):

As you correctly stated, you can store data onchain either as part of logs or in smart contracts. As with all things for SVM vs EVM, there's a few small differences though:

- Logs vs Events: On EVM, Events cost a bit of gas, whereas logging is completely free on Solana (except for potentially a few extra Compute Units, but these don't cost you anything unless you're working with priority fees). It has the downside however, that logs can get truncated on Solana if they are too long. For this reason, Solana introduced the noop ("no-operation") program, that does nothing except taking in some call data. This way, your logs get stored as call data and don't suffer from truncation. You can use it with it's rust crate [here](https://crates.io/crates/spl-noop).
- PDA storage vs Smart Contract Storage: On EVM, I assume data gets written directly to the smart contract (not a complete expert on this). On Solana, each program can own sub-accounts called PDAs, in which it can store data for which it has to deposit an amount of lamports called rent proportional to the amount of data stored. There's a number of questions on this site relating to the details PDAs with [this one](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/26/what-is-a-program-derived-address-pda-exactly) and [this one](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/974/how-to-create-a-pda-and-enable-data-storage) being a good start.

Overall, the key difference (which also explains the cost difference) is that PDA data is accessible and readable by onchain programs, whereas log data is not, so keep this in mind when deciding which way works best for your usecase.